# How to fix dark gray backgound on startActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Sorry, poor my English skill.

I have 2 activities, Splash and Main.

1. LaunchMode of MainActivity is singleTask.
2. SplashActivity has called MainActivty 1 second waiting by Thread. and SplashActivity.finish().

**Question)**

My App is not run. 
And starting by intent filter, SplashAcitivity is good worked.

But, MainActivity gives me gray screen. (gray is not my layout background color) After 0.5 seconds, fill my layout.

But, Starting by launcher, this is not occurred. Same that, when MainAcitivity was background, Intent filter start app.

How to fix dark gray backgound on startActivity?

Comment: @J Tiger make sure you are not doing long task in UI thread inside oncreate() of your activity, also post your code

Comment: @J Tiger please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two item to your splashActivity and MainActivity's theme:

```
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
        <!-- set your splash background drawable or color -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/abc_item_background_holo_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MainTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
```

And remove the animation between these two acitivities. Start the MainActivity like this:

```
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(context, 0, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent(/* mainAcitivity's action or classname */); 
    context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    splashActivity.finish();
```